# Strange value when parsing output in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

Trying to make a script to unlock all locked files inside a folder, by using Windows' `handle.exe`. But when I split the output the filename value is .... weird (all other values are Ok).

The sample output of the `handle.exe` is this:

```
REM  perl.exe           pid: 12532  type: File          PCNAME\UserName          144: C:\dev\massunlocker\Eula.txt
REM  a perl.exe
REM  b pid:
REM  c 12532
REM  d type:
REM  e File
REM  f PCNAME\UserName
REM  g 144:
REM  h C:\dev\massunlocker\Eula.txt
```

So, from this I need `c`, `g`, and `h`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 delims= " %%a in ( 'handle64.exe C:\dev\massunlocker\sample-dir -u -nobanner' ) do (
    REM echo a = "%%a"
    REM echo b = "%%b"
    REM echo c = "%%c"
    REM echo d = "%%d"
    REM echo e = "%%e"
    REM echo f = "%%f"
    REM echo g = "%%g"
    REM echo h = "%%h"
    echo [%%h]
)


:end
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
```

First 2 are fine, but the `%%h` is hmm weird (edited)?

```
]C:\dev\massunlocker\sample-dir\ae\pdf
]C:\dev\massunlocker\sample-dir
]C:\dev\massunlocker\sample-dir\ae
```

Why its not this? :

```
[C:\dev\massunlocker\sample-dir\ae\pdf]
[C:\dev\massunlocker\sample-dir]
[C:\dev\massunlocker\sample-dir\ae]
```

And I can't test it for being dir or a file, it's always comes as true for `not exist`, for example.

Edit: here's an output example with lines uncommented:

```
a = "cmd.exe"
b = "pid:"
c = "1624"
d = "type:"
e = "File"
f = "PCNAME\UserName"
g = "1FC:"
" = "C:\dev\massunlocker\sample-dir
```

note the last line...

P.S. [Handle tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle)

Comment: I am not following your examples.  I am not seeing what you think is `partial`.

Comment: @Squashman sorry, in some other tries I had output seemed partial. but more I do it more it feels like it's just for some strange reason not printing right. but then checking with if exist, for example, doesn't work either.

Comment: Show us the raw output of the handle command.  Would be near impossible to troubleshoot without seeing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you're experiencing is the same as we get from the output of `wmic.exe` within a `For` loop. I'll assume therefore that `handle64.exe` also outputs an extra **`<CR>`**.

If that's the case, you should run the result through an additional `For` loop, in the same way as if it were `WMIC`. Take a look at some of the `WMIC` examples on this site for examples of it in use. Alternatively take a look at [this topic](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266) over on [dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3).

Here's an example of it in use:

```bat
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('
    handle64.exe C:\dev\massunlocker\sample-dir -u -nobanner
')Do For /F "Tokens=1-8" %%B In ("%%A")Do (Rem Echo B = "%%B"
    Rem Echo C = "%%C"
    Rem Echo D = "%%D"
    Rem Echo E = "%%E"
    Rem Echo F = "%%F"
    Rem Echo G = "%%G"
    Rem Echo H = "%%H"
    Rem Echo I = "%%I"
    Echo [%%I])
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet could help.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1-7,* delims= " %%a in ('
    handle64.exe C:\Windows\System32\en-US\Kernel -u -nobanner
  ' ) do (

    REM echo a = "%%a" 
    REM echo b = "%%b"
    REM echo c = "%%c"
    REM echo d = "%%d"
    REM echo e = "%%e"
    REM echo f = "%%f"
    REM echo g = "%%g"
    REM echo h = "%%h"
    for /F "tokens=*" %%H in ("%%~h") do echo h="%%H"  a="%%a"
)
```

Here the `for` loops are

- `%%a` to retrieve the `handle64.exe` output values;
- `%%H` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the `%%h` value returned at a line end.

`wmic` (and **`handle64`** as well) behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (`<CR><CR><LF>`) instead of common `0x0D0A` (`<CR><LF>`).

See Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

**Output** (truncated):

```
==> D:\bat\SO\55065841.bat
h="C:\Windows\System32\en-US\KernelBase.dll.mui"  a="GoldenDict.exe"
h="C:\Windows\System32\en-US\KernelBase.dll.mui"  a="chrome.exe"
h="C:\Windows\System32\en-US\kernel32.dll.mui"  a="chrome.exe"
h="C:\Windows\System32\en-US\KernelBase.dll.mui"  a="AppleChromeDAV.exe"    

==>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean this as an answer.. I just needed the formatted text.
As Compo points out.. there is indeed 0D 0D 0A at the end of the output but not in the middle where the parser should care about it.

Their parser should be better than that.

[image: Hex dump of the output]

As a workaround (as Compo mentioned), take the output of the call and run it through another for loop, it works just fine.  I did the one below with a function call.

```
@echo off
Set THE_DIR=%TEMP%

for /f "delims=" %%a in ( 'handle64.exe %THE_DIR% -u -nobanner' ) do call :Process_Line "%%a"
goto :EOF

:Process_Line 
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 delims= " %%a in ( 'echo %*' ) do (
echo a = "%%a"
echo b = "%%b"
echo c = "%%c"
echo d = "%%d"
echo e = "%%e"
echo f = "%%f"
echo g = "%%g"
echo h = "%%h"
)
goto :EOF
```